# Do I need to mention 'has' ( present perfect tense) twice when connecting the sentences with and?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Is this sentence correct as is, or should I remove the second *has* since that phrase is connected to the preceding one with *and*?

> As Mr. X has replied your email and has requested the 'PDF files' of the project, here please find attached the requested files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As Mr.X has replied **to** your email and requested the 'PDF files' of
>   the project, here please find attached the requested files.

Of your suggestions, I prefer the above.

You may however mean,

> As Mr.X has replied to your email, requesting the PDF files for the project, please find attached the requested files.

Comment: Both as good. But I pick the second one which sounds much better :) @chasly-from-uk

Answer (score 3):

You can generally conjoin two phrases of the same grammatical type to form a phrase of that same type, which can go anywhere either single phrase could go.  This gives the following three equivalent ways of saying your example.  I have indicated with brackets the structure of the conjoined phrase for each version:

[[As Mr. X has replied your email] and [as he has requested the 'PDF files' of the project]], ...
As Mr. X [[has replied your email] and [has requested the 'PDF files' of the project]], ...
As Mr. X has [[replied your email] and [requested the 'PDF files' of the project]], ...

Comment: I understand better now, Thank you. @greg-lee